# Most elegant way to rotate a UILabel; maintain bottom left corner

Tags: ios, uiview, transformation, objective-c-category

Say you want text standing upwards.  Of course, it's easy to rotate it 90degrees:

```
someUIView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(- 90.0f * M_PI / 180.0f);
```

But typically, you want it to **MAINTAIN THE BOTTOM LEFT CORNER**

So, in storyboard IB you position the (horizontal) text where you want **the bottom left corner** to be, and you expect that when the app is running, and the text is vertical, that is where the **"new"** bottom left corner of the vertical text will be.

[image]

Here's a category on UIView...

```
-(void)standOnBottomLeftCorner
    {
    CGPoint org = self.frame.origin;
    org.y += self.frame.size.height;
    self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(- 90.0f * M_PI / 180.0f);
    CGRect nu = self.frame;
    nu.origin = org;
    nu.origin.y -= nu.size.height; 
    self.frame = nu;
    }
```

## However, note:

JRT explains: **"You shouldn't set the frame on a transformed view, it's undefined behaviour."**

Unless I'm drunk, that works ......... but what's the best way?

---

This illustrations show's Matic's very clever idea:

[image]

Comment: What you are most likely looking for is .layer.anchorPoint

Comment: brilliant tip, thanks - but FWIW it's not really rotating around one point (I don't think?)  see diagram!

Comment: That point seems to be (height/width*.5f, .5f) instead of (.0f, 1.0f).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Changing the layer's anchor point will alter the point that transforms work around.

In your case, you'd want to set the anchor point to halfway down the label and half of the height in from the left hand side, as pointed out by Matic:

```
CGRect frame = self.frame;
self.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake((frame.size.height / frame.size.width * 0.5),0.5); // Anchor points are in unit space
self.frame = frame; // Moving the anchor point moves the layer's position, this is a simple way to re-set
CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(- 90.0f * M_PI / 180.0f); // Performs the rotation
self.transform = rotate;
```

Done. You shouldn't set the frame on a transformed view, it's undefined behaviour.

Comment: Ah!  I guess then you'd just move it to the right, by the width of the new upright object.  Or perhaps since you say ".. frame on a transformed view, it's undefined behaviour.." maybe it would be better to use the height of the original?

Comment: Awesome tip that my suggested function is no good, because it's setting a transformed frame, thanks

Comment: Oh I think I've missed a bit. You want the bottom left to be the bottom left from the point of view of the viewer, not the text. You need to add an additional transform as well in that case. I'll update the answer.

Comment: thanks @jrturton -- youknow, Matic had the great idea of using your rotation, but just around that "other" point ... perhaps that's even easier (note new image!)

Comment: Oh, nice! That should be the answer.

Comment: I've updated this answer for the record, if Matic answers feel free to accept his instead!

Comment: A doubly awesome solution, I didn't know about anchorPoint and would never have realised about the "matic point".  Cheers guys